# R: meta-analysis CI of proportion not bounded correctly

Tags: r, confidence-interval

```
library(metafor)
rma(yi = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.14, 0.3), vi = c(0.12, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1))
```

I am fitting a random effects meta-analytic model of single proportions on 4 studies. Since the effect sizes are all proportions, they are bounded between 0 and 1, and so should the confidence intervals. However, the actual output shows

```
Random-Effects Model (k = 4; tau^2 estimator: REML)

tau^2 (estimated amount of total heterogeneity): 0 (SE = 0.1220)
tau (square root of estimated tau^2 value):      0
I^2 (total heterogeneity / total variability):   0.00%
H^2 (total variability / sampling variability):  1.00

Test for Heterogeneity: 
Q(df = 3) = 0.2372, p-val = 0.9714

Model Results:

estimate       se     zval     pval    ci.lb    ci.ub          
  0.2175   0.1936   1.1232   0.2614  -0.1620   0.5970          

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

i.e. the CI is (-0.162, 0.597). How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can treat the lower bound as 0. Or you could use logit transformed proportions (log odds) for the meta-analysis. After the back-transformation, the resulting estimate and CI bounds must be between 0 and 1. Or you could directly switch to a logistic mixed-effects model for your analysis (see `help(rma.glmm)`). The latter is also based on log odds and hence will give you values between 0 and 1 after the back-transformation.